# Replace the value of one item of single case discriminated union?

Tags: f#

See I have a single case discriminated union

```
type R = R of string * int * sting option * .....
```

And I got a value of `R`.

```
let r: R = getAValue ()
```

Now I need to replace the first item of `r` to an empty string and keep all other value. How to do it? Record type has the `with` construct

```
let r' = { r with Item1 = "" }
```

I know it can use 'pattern match' to extract all the items and create a new one. But it seems very cumbersome.

Comment: Why don't you use a record type?  If you only need the one case, then I would have thought that a record would work better here.

Comment: The code uses a lot of single case DU. It's always hard for me to choose between single case DU vs record type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you do not want to involve reflection, do you?

Then, I believe your only option would be using pattern matching. The (quite limited) burden would be defining the `r-ity` of your type `R`as a pattern for matching.

Let's assume, for example, that your R wraps a tuple of 3 elements, i.e. has r-ity 3:

```
type R = R of string * int * string option
```

In this case all you need is to do define the following function:

```
let modR = function
| R(x,y,z) -> R("",y,z)
```

The signature of `modR` is `R -> R`, a quick check of your scenario:

```
let r = R("abc",1,None)
modR r
```

in fsi brings back

```
> 
val it : R = R ("",1,None)
```

All you would need for applying the above to your specific `R` is set the actual r-ity of your type into the pattern.

***UPDATE:*** As [Fyodor Soikin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180286/fyodor-soikin) pointed, a matching function isn't needed at all for unwrapping a single-case DU (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions#unwrapping-discriminated-unions)). The sought convertion function definition may be defined as simple as

```
let modR (R(_,y,z)) = R("",y,z)
```

***UPDATE2:*** While considering the comment from [ca9163d9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825920/ca9163d9) I recalled just another flavor of pattern matching, namely [as Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#as-pattern). Using it while implementing the sought conversion in the form of DU member gives:

```
type R = R of string * int * string option with
    member self.modR() = let R(_,b,c) as x = self in R("",b,c)
```

Also @FyodorSoikin and @kaefer have pointed out in the comments that `as x` form isn't required for the simple DU unwrapping, similarly to terser `modR` function definition above:

```
    member self.modR() = let (R(_,b,c)) = self in R("",b,c)
```

Comment: Maybe I should add the function as a member of the DU.

Comment: You can put the pattern match right in the argument list. Drop the `function |` syntax.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: You're right, for unwrapping a single-case DU matching function isn't needed at all! Thank you, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ca9163d9: your comment recalled me about just another flavor of the pattern matching, thank you. See my **Update2** to the answer.

Comment: The `as x` part is also not necessary in your "update 2".

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: if dropping `as x` then `member self.modR() = let R(_,b,c) = self in R("",b,c)` wouldn't compile. Unless you meant `static member  modR(R(_,b,c)) = R("",b,c)`

Comment: @GeneBelitski You probably want `member self.modR() = let (R(_,b,c)) = self in R("",b,c)` without binding to an unused variable

Comment: Can the `modR` be defined as `type R = R of string * int * string option with
    member self.modR() = function R(_,b,c) -> R("",b,c);;`?

Comment: No, it can't. Look up what `function` means.

Comment: @kaefer Yes! This is it, parenthesis after `let` do the DU unwrapping, same to my static member case, thank you.